# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'. In SQL Server at CASE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case, where-clause, procedure

```
SELECT 
    d.district_id, d.district_name, d1.district_id, d1.district_name
FROM 
    tbl_district d, tbl_district d1 
WHERE
     CASE
        WHEN (d.district_id % 2) != 0 
           THEN d.district_id 
     END
     AND d1.district_id = d.district_id+1;
```

Comment: you need to compare the result of case statement with something. What exactly is your goal?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to filter the odd numbers

```
SELECT 
    d.district_id, d.district_name, d1.district_id, d1.district_name
FROM 
    tbl_district d 
INNER JOIN tbl_district d1 
        ON d1.district_id = d.district_id+1
WHERE (d.district_id % 2) != 0
```

Also start using `INNER JOIN` instead of old style comma separated join

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` then you can use `LEAD` window function

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Lead(district_id)OVER(ORDER BY district_id) AS next_dst,
               Lead(district_name)OVER(ORDER BY district_id) AS next_name
        FROM   tbl_district ) a
WHERE  a.district_id + 1 = a.next_dst
       AND ( district_id % 2 ) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

"Case when" is a value, it is not a logical operation.

For example:

```
 SELECT 
d.district_id, d.district_name, d1.district_id, d1.district_name
FROM 
tbl_district d, tbl_district d1 
WHERE
 CASE
    WHEN (d.district_id % 2) != 0 
       THEN d.district_id 
 END+1 = d1.district_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EvenOdd_District]
AS
BEGIN

      SELECT d.district_id ,d.district_name,d1.district_id ,d1.district_name
      FROM tbl_district d,tbl_district d1 WHERE d.district_id=
         CASE
            when (d.district_id%2)!=0 then d.district_id 
         END
         AND d1.district_id=d.district_id+1;
END
```